# javascript - how to insert a script tag to div?

Tags: javascript

How to do that:

```
document.getElementById('target').innertHTML = "&lt;script&gt; alert(1); &lt;script&gt;";
<div id="target"></div>
```

script will be print on browser like a string.How to do is as script ?

Answer (score 9):

I believe it is better to use pure DOM manipulation. Like this :

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
s.value = 'alert(1)';
document.getElementById('target').appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying my question. I am voting for you.

Answer (score 5):

Just don't escape your `<` and `>`s:

```
document.getElementById('target').innertHTML = "<script> alert(1); <\/script>";
```

Comment: You might want to use `<\/script>` so the `script` tag that that code is in doesn't get closed in the middle of a string literal.

Comment: don't write it in script tags, i have used creatElement . Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use innerHTML for scripts anymore. It won't work and the console will not show any error. Instead you dynamically add scripts.

This is for external scripts:

```
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.src = "http://www.example.com/my-script.js";
target.appendChild(newScript);
```

And this is for inline scripts:

```
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
var inlineScript = document.createTextNode("alert('Hello World!');");
newScript.appendChild(inlineScript); 
target.appendChild(newScript);
```

Credit to Daniel Crabtree

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('target').innertHTML = '<script type="text/javascript"> alert(1); </script>';
```

Comment: This doesn't execute/ evaluate the injected script.