# Script-Tags generated by Javascript do not work?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm creating a webpage using php, mysql, html5&css3 and javascript (ajax).
To improve the performance, i decided to use AJAX to get only the content div (`<div id="content">`) that actually changes, i dont want to reload the whole code all the time. That works as follows: after having received the new content from a php-file, javascript does the following:
`document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = new_content;`
After that, the `new_content` is well displayed...

Now the Problem:
In the `new_content`, i have some javascript, too, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="JAVASCRIPT">
  alert('Hello!');
   ...
</script>
```

Unfortunately, when inserting it in the div, it isn't executed at all...
when calling the php-file "naturally", the javascript code does what i want it to do, so there's no error in it.

Thanks in advance



EDIT: Problem is solved, i included jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

and used `$("#content").html(new_content);` in javascript as mentioned below.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to load js dynamically rather than just the content?

Comment: You have to execute this code in some way after loading it. The browser is done executing JS after the page has finished and will only react to events. So you have to wrap your code into a function that is executable or eval it (which would be worse).

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266119/javascript-how-to-insert-a-script-tag-to-div). It is nice to search before asking..

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)'s `$.html`. It will automatically execute scripts for you.

```
$("#content").html(new_content);
```

Comment: There are so many other Javascript libraries than jQuery around, many of them far better suited to many tasks than jQuery. When a generic JS question is asked, "USE JQUERY" isn't always the answer without knowing (far) more context.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: because jquery $.html is a simple way to go in this case and jquery is popular, most people know about it

Comment: But you don't know if he can use jQuery, or if he doesn't want to use it on purpose, to learn generic Javascript, or if he uses libraries which cannot cooperate with jQuery. Your answer is, at the very least, incomplete, and should be formulated as a recommendation, not a solution. I wholly agree a library is the preferable solution for cross-browser reasons, but [recommending jQuery as the Swiss Army Knife solution for every conceivable problem is even considered a meme here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/219504).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, by default script execution is disabled when just replacing HTML - makes sense if you look at it. You should really consider using a library like jQuery or Mootools to abstract issues like this away.

If you look at Mootools' [`Request.HTML`](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Request/Request.HTML.js) implementation you'll see it has its `evalScripts` option defaulting to true, which later on during the call results in this bit of code being executed:

```
    response.html = text.stripScripts(function(script){
        response.javascript = script;
    });

            ...

    if (options.evalScripts) Browser.exec(response.javascript);
```

However this probably won't work on its own without Mootools' other bits of browser-abstracting code in place, so yes I'd definitely recommend including a library on your project.